# Adding time variable to IFTTT recipe

Tags: android, variables, ifttt

I have a recipe that texts "I'll be home in 45 mins" when I leave a certain area.

Is it possible to add a variable to the text so it reads "I'll be home at [current time + 45 mins]"?

(It's from the recipe 'send a message from your phone when you leave a specific area'.)

Comment: If you’re triggering the text message action using the location-based trigger, there’s no means of adding another variable other than what is provided by the services.  If you use iOS, you could do it with [**Workflow**](https://workflow.is) and IFTTT combined.

Comment: Ok, in the ingredients you can't add =DATE() +45 or something?

Comment: Ingredients for *IFTTT* actions are pre-defined.  I've never come across an instance where you could define your own ingredients, with the exception of the *Workflow* trigger that I mentioned before.  I suspect you would have found the option to add you own ingredient by now if it were possible.  *IFTTT* isn't intended to be a programming tool or use complex rules, unfortunately.  There may be other ways to achieve what you want, but you'll have to put a creative thinking hat on.

Comment: You can [become a partner](https://platform.ifttt.com/) and add your own service